# Kerberos - keytab file only works with certain password

Tags: keycloak, kerberos, keytab

I am trying to implement Kerberos Integration for Keycloak on a Windows domain.
I have added an ldap provider in Keycloak and setup my connection with AD which all works.

I am testing it out on a sandbox environment
Domain: SANDBOX.NET
DC: KEYTEST-DC
App server where keycloak is running: KEYTEST-APP
Client machine to test the auto login with kerberos: KEYTEST-CLIENT

I started with the following actions (done on the DC with a DC admin account)

1. Create a new AD service user with the same name as the machine name where keycloak is running
   First Name: KEYTEST-APP
   User logon name: HTTP/keytest-app.sandbox.net
   Password: S@ndM@n
2. Set the spn for this user
   setspn -A HTTP/keytest-app.sandbox.net@SANDBOX.NET KEYTEST-APP
3. Create KeyTab file

   ktpass /out keycloak.keytab /princ HTTP/keytest-app.sandbox.net@SANDBOX.NET /mapuser KEYTEST-APP@SANDBOX.NET /pass S@ndM@n
4. Copy the keytab file to the app server and use it to configure kerberos in keycloak
   Kerberos Realm: SANDBOX.NET
   Server Principal: HTTP/keytest-app.sandbox.net@SANDBOX.NET
   Keytab: location of the keytab file

I did an initial test and everything worked perfectly.

Then I wanted to document the whole process so I started again, but choose svc_keycloak as the name for my AD service user as I found other documentation which didn't specify that the name must match that of the app server.
I also chose a different password, but when I tested this it didn't work.
Error in keycloak: `SPNEGO login failed: java.security.PrivilegedActionException: GSSException: Failure unspecified at GSS-API level (Mechanism level: Checksum failed)`

Eventually I found out, it only worked with the svc_keycloak user when I used the S@ndM@n password in the ktpass command, even though this was the password from the KEYTEST-APP user.

Then I did a lot of tests, deleted the KEYTEST-APP user, created new DC admin accounts, changed passwords. Yet kerberos only worked when I used S@ndM@n as the password in the ktpass command (With whatever user I tried).

In the end I started from zero, new DC, new app server, configured everything from scratch.
This time I started with the new service user: svc_keycloak and a whole new password, but again same error in keycloak.
Then I created the user KEYTEST-APP again and gave it the password S@ndM@n (Maybe I should have picked a different password here and I should start again from scratch) and now it all worked again.
Testing with svc_keycloak, it again also worked with if I gave S@ndM@n as password in the ktpass command.

And it even keeps on working after deleting the KEYTEST-APP user, so somewhere the password must still be stored??
I noticed when I deleted the KEYTEST-APP user I still got Service Principal Names when executing:
setspn -l KEYTEST-APP

After some research (because my knowledge about kerberos is very limited) I found out that this is because KEYTEST-APP is also a computer account.
As far as I have found, every computer account has its own password, but these are completely random.

I just want to find out why it only works with the S@ndM@n password. Is this because this is the first password I used for the user with the same name as the app server? Then there must be some way to update this?
Or maybe I have overlooked something and someone sees the problem in my config.

Thx,
Remi